# What Delphi components ship with unit tests?

Tags: delphi, unit-testing, dunit

Given the popularity of unit testing, and the inclusion of DUnit with Delphi, has this been embraced by any component vendors who have released their source along with a suite of unit tests?

I'm looking for examples to share with other developers.

Comment: This is setting up to be a list question, which StackOverflow kind of tries to discourage.  But check out DeHL and OmniThreadLibrary.

Comment: And our [mORMot Open source project](http://synopse.info) (Client-Server RESTful ORM with SOA). It is shipped with about [6,000,000 regression tests](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SQLite3/TestSQL3.dpr).

Comment: Maybe you could rephrase it to be "what's the best example of professional-grade DUnit tests?"

Comment: Component testing is not very well suited for unit testing since most components are all about GUI behaviour and not so much about testable behaviour.

Comment: 'Not constructive'...  'expect answers to generally involve facts, references'...  isn't that what this question is about?  (facts, references - it's not an opinion if a component library ships with unit tests)

Comment: The not-constructive real reason it was closed is that ListsOfX Questions are discouraged because they have N answers instead of 1 answer.

Answer (score 6):

[DWScript](http://code.google.com/p/dwscript/) ships with a large collection of DUnit-based tests, most of them "hand-made", and also leverages [Delphi Code Coverage](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-code-coverage/) (see also the [DCC Wizard](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-code-coverage-wizard/) project).